# Is there a way to wrap code neatly in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, formatting, word-wrap, android-studio-3.0

I've enabled word wrap in the editor, but it doesn't align to the relevant scope, which looks unnecessarily messy.

Here is an example of the automatic behavior:
***word-wrap-default***

[image]

Here is an example of what I'd *like* the automatic behavior to be:
***word-wrap-preferred***

[image]

Is there a way to set this up in Android Studio 3.0?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Android Studio 3.0 following should help:

***File > Settings > Editor > General > Soft Wraps > & checking "Use original lines indent for wrapped parts"***

[image]

Comment: This is not what I am asking, however pointed me in a direction: **solved** by going into Settings > Editor > General > Soft Wraps > & checking "_Use original lines indent for wrapped parts_"!

Comment: @ArianaW. I have corrected the answer , can you accept it please!